# C and data structure

Tags: c, data-structures

what will be the output of the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i=10;
    void *ptr=&i;
    printf("%f",*(float *)ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be 10.000000 but the output given by the compiler is 0.000000.why?

Comment: `ptr` doesn't point to a floating point value. Dereferencing the pointer using the wrong type breaks strict aliasing and leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen.

Comment: As for the implementation-specific reason you don't get the expected value, it's because floating-point values and integer values are stored using different formats.

Comment: `printf("%f", (float)*(int*)ptr);`